# Execute "go to Symbol in File" programmatically in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to jump to an existing symbol in file from Extension?

Something of the sort:

```typescript
goToSymbol(symbol: string)
```

P.S. I don't want to provide a `DocumentSymbolProvider`. How to use existing ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```typescript
async function getSymbols(document: TextDocument): Promise<DocumentSymbol[]> {
    return await commands.executeCommand<DocumentSymbol[]>('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider', document.uri) || [];
}

async function goToSymbol(document: TextDocument, symbolName: string) {
    const symbols = await getSymbols(document);
    const findSymbol = symbols.find(symbol => symbol.name === symbolName);
    const activeTextEditor = window.activeTextEditor;
    if (findSymbol && activeTextEditor) {
        activeTextEditor.revealRange(findSymbol.range, vscode.TextEditorRevealType.AtTop);
        activeTextEditor.selection = new Selection(findSymbol.range.start, findSymbol.range.start);
    }
}
```

> Note: the code above should be enough to go to symbol of 1 lvl.
>
> Nested symbols accessible as `.children` (on every element of `symbols`)